# Two words crossing

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords

[image]

**34 white squares to be filled with a letter each**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The clues on the left** give these:

An X:

> **ACROSS** (A cross)

A II:

> **TWO**

A 10:

> **ANX** (An X)

---

Behind:

> **DOWN**

Not an other:

> **ONE**

Not a head:

> **BEHIND**

---

**Next ...**

> Roughly preserving the layout, and replacing cardinal numerals with corresponding numbers, we have a proper set of crossword clues for the right side crossword:
>
>    $\small\underline{\text{ACROSS}}$
>    `2.  An X`
>    $\small\underline{\text{DOWN}}$
>    `1.  Behind`
>
>  to which the answers are   **ACROSS**   and   **DOWN**   respectively.

which of course makes sense.
Thanks TSL denizens for the right final words, though the reasoning to get there gets a little twisted -

> Each group of clues on the left has a clue that is also an answer to a different clue.
>    "An X" yields "Across", but is also the answer to "A 10".
>    "Behind" yields "Down", but is also the answer to "Not a head".
>  The final clues, "An X" and "Behind", just give their left-side answers as their right-side answers.

**Completed puzzle**, courtesy of OP:

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer:

I'm not sure what to do with the right side as yet, but here's what I've got for the left.

An X:

> LETTER

A II:

> TWO

A 10:

> TEN

Behind:

> BACK

Not an other:

> Not sure

Not a head:

> BEHIND